# "pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None" causes UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported

Tags: python, pandas

I noticed this message only today and could not find any notification on the pandas documentation web...

I use a simple way to load all sheets into dictionary of dataframes:

```
filename = "data.xlsx"
sheets_dict = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=None)
```

and it started to cause warning shown below...

is it a bug? or I should start using different method?
If not a bug, - please advise the option.

```
openpyxl\worksheet\_reader.py:312: UserWarning: Slicer List extension is not supported and will be removed
```

Answer (score 1):

Its the warning from openpyxl. If you use the default engine on pandas to load each Excel file, the warning goes away, but the time it takes for each file goes up to 5 or even 6 seconds. You can ignore those warnings.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')
```